Error when launching an instance in OpenStack (I just configured a self-service network)
PROBLEM: We deployed OpenStack in a cluster and until now we could launch instances using a provider (flat) network. Today we configured a self-service network to be able to use vxlan as well, although now we get an error when launching the instance with the new self-service network and the previous provider network. Here's the collection of errors I found in OpenStack logs and the Dashboard (Horizon):
ERRORS
Horizon
Error/Fault:

Message
Exceeded maximum number of retries. Exhausted all hosts available for retrying build failures for instance fe6fdc06-5ef8-4ace-8738-15a270dd2809.


Code 500


Details
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/nova/conductor/manager.py", line 705, in build_instances raise exception.MaxRetriesExceeded(reason=msg) nova.exception.MaxRetriesExceeded: Exceeded maximum number of retries. Exhausted all hosts available for retrying build failures for instance fe6fdc06-5ef8-4ace-8738-15a270dd2809.

Neutron
Error 1 (neutron_dhcp_agent, in compute node):

ERROR neutron.agent.dhcp.agent OSError: [Errno 38] failed to open netns

Error 2 (neutron-openvswitch-agent, in controller node):

2024-07-28 16:09:09.564 401936 ERROR neutron.agent.linux.utils [None req-08afcc05-b578-4440-8380-7478e8f295b1 - - - - - -] Exit code: 1; Cmd: ['iptables-save', '-t', 'raw']; Stdin: ; Stdout: ; Stderr: iptables-save v1.8.10 (legacy): Cannot initialize: Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)

Warn 1 (ovs_vswitchd, in compute node):

2024-07-11T22:05:15.020Z|34365|bridge|WARN|could not open network device tapb6300b35-d0 (No such device)
2024-07-11T22:05:15.034Z|34366|bridge|WARN|could not open network device tapbd42e760-bc (No such device)

Nova
Error 1 (nova-compute):

2024-07-11 22:08:26.463 1339 ERROR nova.compute.manager nova.exception.InvalidDiskInfo: Disk info file is invalid: qemu-img failed to execute on /var/lib/nova/instances/0ae813eb-8d8d-4eac-aada-efa6e8d89597/disk : Unexpected error while running command.

More information that might be useful about neutron configuration:
[ml2]

type_drivers = flat,vlan,local,vxlan

tenant_network_types = vxlan,local

mechanism_drivers = openvswitch


Can you share your entire neutron config? Although it seems to be supported, I don't mix tenant_network_types. In my environments this is my ml2 config (it's difficult to read as a comment):
[ml2] type_drivers = flat,vlan,vxlan tenant_network_types = vxlan -#- [ml2_type_flat] flat_networks = provider -#- [ml2_type_vlan] network_vlan_ranges = provider
And then here's the ovs bridge mapping: [ovs] bridge_mappings = provider:br-provider

Hi @eblock ! I have the same configuration as you do, I also tried removing local from type_drivers and tenant_network_types but the error persists.
I think the issue might be the dhcp agent as it manages the netns which is giving trouble now.

And is the dhcp agent logging errors? Or is it up and running?

Is logging the error I wrote above:
ERROR neutron.agent.dhcp.agent OSError: [Errno 38] failed to open netns


How did you deploy openstack and which version? Can you manually run ip netns ls and see if that works? I remember years ago when I had to install some missing package for netns to work, but I'm not sure if this is the case here.
